# How to use a Client Certificate with ftp_ssl_connect

Tags: php, ssl, ftps

I'm looking for the best method to work with an FTP server over an SSL connection. (Generally, pushing a file up as well as getting a list of files on the server). One requirement for this project is that I must use a client side X.509 certificate as part of the authentication process.

Can I use a client certificate using the php function ftp_ssl_connect. If so, how? The only other option I've been able to identify would be using curl to work via FTPS.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's stream context functions which [allow setting SSL client certificates](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php). Use the created context with standard functions like `fopen`.

Comment: Unfortunately these open a new connection for every file operation you do. There is no way to save a connection handler and reusing this multiple times to prevent drowning the server in connection attempts.