# PHP FTPS with Certificate

Tags: php, curl, ftps

I'm looking for a way to connect to a FTPS server from PHP and I need to send a client certificate. I looked at the related questions, but they don't answer the question:

[How to use a Client Certificate with ftp_ssl_connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027712/how-to-use-a-client-certificate-with-ftp-ssl-connect)
[Connecting to FTPS using PHP and certificate as auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390907/connecting-to-ftps-using-php-and-certificate-as-auth)

I now connect using ftp_ssl_connect but I don't see a way to send a certificate. Is the only possibility to rewrite the code and use something like curl? Or are there other options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308270/using-curl-in-php-with-ca-certificate-client-certificate-and-private-key-in-s

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed using curl. There is no option to do this via ftp_ssl_connect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390907/connecting-to-ftps-using-php-and-certificate-as-auth

Comment: I have just answered the second question mentioned in these comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19497103/1738274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer is to use CURL. The answer of J Griffiths: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497103/1738274 gives you an idea how to fix this.